# Are people shy to use upvotes?

Tags: discussion, voting, up-votes

I've recently seem more and more cases where situation is following: a question with zero upvotes and an one or more correct answers also with zero upvotes. Interesting thing is that often it's indicated in the comment that the answer is correct or it might be correct.

I'm really not sure where is it coming from. Is it because now you cannot un-upvote and answer once a certain time has passed? Or is it that people just don't care about upvoting at all?

Anyway, it transmits kind of a message *"you've wasted your time answering that question and no one even cares about it"*. Which I find it quite demotivating.

Few examples I've stumbled upon myself:

- [Django QuerySet - How to "disable" previous filtered value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980965/django-queryset-how-to-disable-previous-filtered-value/)
- [python 2.7.3 not executing on apache 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15789615/python-2-7-3-not-executing-on-apache-2-2/)
- [How to use gunicorn as django test server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16235992/how-to-use-gunicorn-as-django-test-server/)
- [Tornado: Can I run code after calling self.finish() in an asynchronous RequestHandler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696291/tornado-can-i-run-code-after-calling-self-finish-in-an-asynchronous-requestha/)
- [In tornado, how can I use static_url() in a class without tornado.web.RequestHandler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696033/in-tornado-how-can-i-use-static-url-in-a-class-without-tornado-web-requesthan)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206881/make-twisted-server-reload-my-new-changes/

Comment: You are involved in all those examples...yet you didn't vote on any of it, I gather? Why not? Might that somehow explain why others didn't vote either?

Comment: @vartec I tend to be far far far more likely to up-vote posts where someone uses questions as a [Teachable Moment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19529752/814064) that will help people arriving on the page for years to come.

Comment: @vartac: Sorry, but you lost me. "Why aren't people upvoting? Well, I don't upvote because people don't vote for me, or the poster doesn't upvote like I think they should. In fact, when I did upvote and they didn't appreciate it, I even un-upvoted to punish them." So you're complaining that people don't participate, while you find (unreasonable) excuses for not participating yourself and take back votes as a punitive measure (means of punishing people) instead of as a measure of quality as they're intended. Have I got that right?

Comment: @vartec: Voting (up or down) is a major part of participating. Removing an upvote as a means of punishment (as you say you do in your comment to Bart above) is not participating. Voting should be based on the **quality of the question or answer**, not as a punishment because others vote or not. And complaining about people not participating in one aspect of the site when you're stating you intentionally avoid that same participation is simply hypocritical - "You should do what I say, and ignore the fact I don't do it myself.".

Comment: I answer questions all the time without caring if anyone notices or not. Just because someone doesn't find the answer helpful right this second doesn't mean it won't help in the future. People very frequently forget that SO isn't about **your reputation**. It's a knowledge base for **future readers** of the site. Whether it immediately benefits you by getting you upvotes should not affect your answering even a little. If you find yourself often removing votes because you voted wrong, then vote less quickly in the first place. (BTW, I have 12.2K votes currently on SO, so I **do** participate.)

Comment: @KenWhite: I have 45K rep on SO and getting 80 a day just by doing absolutely nothing, so I don't care about rep. What I do care about is my time. I don't like to waste it. If I wrote an answer that no one bothers to acknowledge, I feel I've wasted my time writing it.

Comment: @KenWhite: are you happy with things like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339754/put-tablet-in-androidmanifest/19341943#19341943?

Comment: Ah, got it. So then you've wasted time reading the question in the first place, which means you've wasted your time looking at the list of questions, which means you've wasted your time at SO totally. Ok. So why go to SO at all? (I also vote to close low quality questions, edit those that can be saved, and vote to migrate questions that belong elsewhere. Posting a link to one specific question is meaningless. I can point to thousands of poor ones, and thousands of good ones as well.) My point is the "I'm complaining because others behave like I do" attitude of your entire post is wrong.

Comment: No, I probably can't (and won't bother to try). I'm basing my comments here on **what you yourself wrote here**. Your entire question is a complaint about people not voting, while at the same time you say you don't vote (and go back to retract votes you did make). That's hypocritical, clearly, based on your own words, typed by your own fingers. How much more clearly can I say it? Other than, of course, having downvoted your question. Ironic, huh? I **voted**. :-)

Comment: I didn't post a complaint on Meta about people behaving in the same way I do, did I? :-) I also never connected the act of answering with the act of voting; I specifically said answering was about sharing knowledge. No deflection on my part - that's all coming from your keyboard. I'm through here. Good luck.

Comment: @Bart: there http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202948/should-i-upvote-questions-im-answering

Answer (score 4):

I do not believe we can **force** people to upvote.
Sometimes an answer seems just too trivial and after-handedly, so despite its usefulness it does not seem to merit an upvote.

Personally, if I see a trivial question that gets an even more trivial answer (something like Q:"How to use function `foo`??" A:"here's how it's done - just read the one-liner example in the manual and copy-paste it") I prefer to ignore it altogether without any voting.

Comment: Your answer is definitely correct but I am not sure if it's non-trivial enough to merit an upvote :-)

Comment: @JanDvorak indeed. feel free to not-upvote I'll totaly understand. But I'll upvote your comment, though ;)

Comment: Well, except in that case the argument would be that these kind of questions should be deleted altogether.