# Should I upvote questions I'm answering?

Tags: discussion, questions, up-votes

Sometimes I answer questions that are kind of OK, neither bad enough to downvote, nor good enough to upvote (although they probably could become good ones with edits).

Per answers to [Should I upvote "bad" questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12772/should-i-upvote-bad-questions) seems that I'm doing the right thing. But on the other hand comments to my recent question here [Are people shy to use upvotes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202821/are-people-shy-to-use-upvotes) suggest, that I shouldn't expect answers to be accepted or upvoted if I "don't participate" by upvoting the question.

Should I really upvote the question just because I think it's worth my time to answer it?

Comment: P.s. my comment on your other question was not meant as a "you should have voted yourself", but rather a "you didn't find anything to vote on. What caused that and might that explain why other users would have skipped as well".

Comment: @Bart: I have seens tons of questions that don't get upvoted, yet have highly upvoted answers. I've even seen downvoted questions with highly upvoted answers.

Comment: Sure. Your point being?

Comment: @Bart: my point being that there isn't that strict relation between quality of the question and the exposure it gets.

Comment: "Are people shy to use upvotes?" is a ridiculous question. People are *much* too generous with upvotes on awful questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is **no correlation between votes and providing an answer** to a question. Some people create such by only answering questions they find interesting (thus by definition deserving an upvote), but I can remember answering questions without voting or even downvoting (though I'll more likely leave a comment if I think it's a poor question).

Bottom line: **voting is entirely up to your discretion**, do as you see fit as long as it doesn't qualify as vote-fraud.

Answer (score 2):

You are entirely free to vote as you see fit. If you think the question is particularly good, vote it up. If you think it's a reasonable question, deserves to be on the site, and deserves an answer but no upvote, so be it. This is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you **should** do. It is totally up to you.

If you think it's worth an upvote then upvote. If not then don't.

I absolutely **don't** upvote all questions I answer.

Voting is a personal issue. It's like asking: *Should I like this question?*

Answer (score 1):

When upvoting, I always ask myself: is that a question that others may find **helpful and useful**? Is it **clear and understandable** to many (if not all)?

Many of questions I answer are of that type but definitely not all of them. Some are beginners' questions that are poor quality. I answer them to help someone but they should not be examples for others to learn from.

But you may have different criteria, it's up to you.

Comment: Agree!! I also take it, that should someone else have the same problem, would he be able to understand the question and answer and will it provide him with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to **vote** on all questions I answer. It's not always an upvote, but I rarely leave the question without any vote.

Since I decided to answer the question it means that I have read it, understood it, and can with a good chance determine whether he had *shown research effort and the question is useful and clear*, which is the text for the upvote button.